# Inequality problem, theorem is missing

Tags: inequality

I have some problems in proving following inequality:

For $0<s<1$, $x,y>0$:

$sx^2+(1-s)y^2 \ge (sx+(1-s)y)^2$

My simulation says it's correct, but I can't find the theorem I have to apply...

Thanks for your help!

Comment: It says $x\mapsto x^2$ is a convex function. You can of course prove the inequality by computation. But if you want to invoke a theorem: What do you know about convex functions?

Comment: I would like to invoke a theorem, but I dont get which theorem that is about convex function could be applied...

Comment: What theorems about convex functions have you already learned?

Comment: Unfortunately just some equivalent definitions so far

Comment: Nothing about "a differentiable function $f$ is convex if and only if …"?

Comment: oh... now I got it! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can verify that $$(sx + (1-s)y)^2 = \left[1-s(1-s)
\frac{(x-y)^2}{sx^2+(1-s)y^2}\right](sx^2+(1-s)y^2).$$

Since the left hand side is positive and $sx^2+(1-s)y^2$ is positive, $1-s(1-s)\frac{(x-y)^2}{sx^2+(1-s)y^2}$ must be positive and less than $1$.